# Maven Transitive dependencies of dependencies in test scope included into a package

Tags: testing, dependencies, maven-3

I don't understand why transitive dependencies of test scope dependencies are included into package (from maven package phase). I'm using maven-war-plugin with default settings.

It doesn't make sense, does it ? The problems arise when you have 10 test scope deps, all with some logging transitive dependencies, and you have to exclude all of them. Not only that one has to do it in compile scope dependencies, but even for test scope deps.

Comment: Which version of maven and which version of maven war plugin? It does not happen for me with maven 3.0.2 and maven war plugin 2.1.1

Comment: I have the same problem with maven 3.0.2 and 3.0.3 and maven-war-plugin 2.1.1 and 2.1-alpha-2, but in my case it happened with provided scope (I have a los of jboss jars in my war, and the dependency is provided). With maven 2.2.1, and maven-war-plugin 2.1-alpha-2 it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven bug [MNG-5150](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5150) breaks at least `jboss-packaging-plugin` as described in [MJBOSSPACK-40](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJBOSSPACK-40).

I would guess that the same bug also breaks `maven-war-plugin`.